# what is IEnumerable do

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

ASP.NET MVC: I fail to understand the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<Role> GetRoles()     // what does this line do?
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mystring"].ToString()))
    {
        // and what does this line do?
        return con.Query<Role>("Usp_GetRoles", null, null, true, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();        
    }
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerble<>` is the interface implemented by *all* collections, including arrays, lists, queues

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: public IEnumerable<Role> GetRoles() what this function does

Comment: It looks up a connection string named "Mystring" from the app config and uses it to open a new SQL Server connection, then executes a stored procedure named "Usp_GetRoles" that returns a number of `Role` objects (the .Query method turns the records into objects when .ToList executes). Since a `List<Role>` is also an `IEnumerable<Role>`, the acquired list is returned as an enumerable of roles which the calling code can enumerate, but they can't `Add` or `Remove` items from the list.

Comment: `public IEnumerable<Role> GetRoles()` defines a public method called `GetRoles` that returns an instance of `IEnumerable<Role>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple term, IEnumerable interface is a generic interface which allows looping over generic or non-generic lists.

As you are using dapper and dapper `Query` only guarantees to hand you an `IEnumerable<T>`. we can convert it to a list as soon as we want to return a result.

```
// GetRoles Method with return type IEnumerable of Role Since the below Query Extension method returns IEnumerable<T>
public IEnumerable<Role> GetRoles()         
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mystring"].ToString()))
        {
            //calling Query Extension method with passing arguments which includes stored procedure name, set of parameters and command type
            return con.Query<Role>("Usp_GetRoles", null, null, true, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Little bit of trivia there, but what's allowing enumeration is merely the presence of a GetEnumerator method, whether it's enforced by IEnumerable or not.